# Unity ARCore Unable to extract resources needed by IL2CPP

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am trying to run a Unity ARCore application from a native android app. I was successful in running the unity application when added as an "aar" library and creating an apk. Problem comes when we add the Unity exported project as a module or as an application bundle(aab). When the android app asks to run the Unity activity, i get a black screen with the following message.

**"Failed to extract resources needed by il2cpp".**

Other forums and questions say that this issue generally shows up when there is lack of space in device. But that is not the case for me. I have ample storage space and i have forced application to internal.

Attached is a screenshot of my Unity project settings
[image]

Can anyone point me towards what might be causing this?

Thank you